Typescript performant way to declare types for onAction
I am currently reading about typescript performance. Came across this excellent read from the typescript team itself.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance
One of the points says, Preferring Base Types Over Unions.
Now, the issue is while declaring types for onAction we do it like
type OnAction = CopyAction | CutAction | CloneAction | ...

The benefit of doing this is, that while adding switch case typescript is properly able to narrow the types for each action. Using the way suggested by the team in the article, we have to typecast action in each case.
So what will be a good way to achieve the same? We have lots of union types which is hampering the performance of typescript.

“Using the way suggested by the team in the article, we have to typecast action in each case.” That doesn’t sound right. You can narrow a base type using a switch statement. Can you include an example of code that isn’t working for you? There’s not enough detail in this question to advise on.

Sure @TimMoore, here is the playground link containing both the way https://shorturl.at/SC8eX

If you're accepting a base type which is wider than the union you meant to accept, then there's nothing you can do but assert that it's narrow again when you need it to be narrow. Maybe like this version shown here. But oof, those must be pretty large unions for this to matter. And if you're writing code that needs to care about each case individually (that is, if your union has N members, you have N blocks of code in your functions that deal with them) then you're going to have performance issues no matter what. How should we proceed with answering this question?
